# Smart mysql search query

Tags: mysql, string, search, full-text-search

I have a mysql **InooDB** table with the following columns **`id, title`**. I've got around *70.000* rows and increasing.

Below you will *find some example rows*. When I search for exp. "**big burgers**" this is what I want it to find and in that order. `id 5` would in this case not be included in the results

Is my order logic bad? Are there some resources that can help me out? How do I do this?

```
+------+--------------------------+-----+------------------------------------+
|id    |title                     |order|explanation                         |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1     |burger place              |  6  |has the second word in search       |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|2     |big burgers               |  1  |This is what is searched            |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|3     |burgers big               |  4  |identical just word order different |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|4     |big city hall             |  5  |has the first word in search        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|5     |red offices               |  /  |not included in results             |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|6     |johns big burgers         |  3  |has what was searched               |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|7     |big burgers chicago       |  2  |starts with what is searched        |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|8     |burgerslicious            |  8  |resebles 1 word in search           |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|9     |bigmans burgers           |  7  |resembles multiple words in search  |
+------+--------------------------+-----+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: [`FULLTEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html), and what else?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? Do you want the results to be in the order or the example or are worried about the structure of your table? Sorry not too sure what you are after.

Comment: @BK435 find them, but not find red offices. Both. But to order them by the order I presented in the table. Thanks.

Comment: @MarcusAdams well I don't know how the query should look like. Thanks.

Comment: Can you share what you've tried @Karington?

Comment: @theatlasroom i want to select the rows and order them like I have shown in the table. Sorry for being unclear. Thanks.

Comment: You need to create a FULLTEXT index and use the query language to select and order your results. FULLTEXT indexes can only be used with MyISAM tables. The MySQL reference is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html)

Comment: @HoboSapiens thank you for your reply. I don't know how to order it. Can you provide an example? Or resource? Checking the link now. Thanks again.

Comment: @HoboSapiens, MySQL provides FULLTEXT indexes on both MyISAM and InnoDB since MySQL 5.6.

Comment: here is a demo code thats not finding or ordering the way I would like it to.
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8ca6b/5

Comment: @BK435 Not really. This just orders by title. What I need is the "smart" ordering. By the logic (I think is good, might be wrong) i presented in the table/question above

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do the FULLTEXT search and order by the relevance score.

```
select id, title, 
       match (title) against ('big burger' with query expansion) score
  from samples 
  where match (title) against ('big burger'  with query expansion)
  order by 3 desc
```

You don't have much control, in MySQL FULLTEXT searching, over the scoring criteria. So it's not possible to guarantee the order you show in your question.  FULLTEXT is basically organized around showing a user some likely choices and letting her choose one.

To add a fulltext index, the table's going to have use the MyISAM access method, unless you're on MySQL version 5.6 or higher.

Comment: i tried you code. Doest really get me where I want to. Maybe I'm doing something wrong? Thanks. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e8ca6b/5

Comment: FULLTEXT works strangely when you have a small collection of text. Try it on your big table. But as I explained, don't expect too much control over the ordering, or finding of variant words.